# Two foreign keys for 1 column?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am trying to design a database , but I have difficulties in setupping the foreign keys. I use InnoDB and phpMyAdmin.

I have 3 tables:

```
1) orders
- order_id
- order_details
- files_id

2) contacts
- contact_id
- contact_details
- files_id

3) files
- filе_id (not primary key, just index)
- filename
```

The idea is the following: a contact and an order can have 0 or more files attached to them. I am trying to setup the foreign keys so **when I delete a contact or an order, it automatically deletes all the files referenced (CASCADE on DELETE).**

**As you might see I need to attach files.file_id with 2 foreign keys - contacts.files_id, orders.files_id. I don't see how to do that or if it is even possible.** Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this instead:

1) orders

- order_id
- order_details

2) contacts

- contact_id
- contact_details

3)orders_Files

- order_id
- file_id

4) contacts_Files

- Contact_id(FK),
- file_id

5) files

- filе_id (primary key,)
- filename

Comment: +1 - however, it is worth noting that deleting an order or contact record will only delete the *relationship* in the relevant `*_Files` table: it will leave the underlying record in the `files` table itself.  (On the other hand, my answer won't cascade anything if the order or contact - rather than the object - is deleted).

Comment: @eggyal aha, I meant they have no longer those files. Now I see. I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to [@MahmoudGamal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14424890) is to consider `orders` and `contacts` to be more specific types of a generic `object`:

```
CREATE TABLE object (
  object_id       SERIAL
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
  order_id        SERIAL,
  order_details   TEXT,
  object_id       BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (object_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (object_id) REFERENCES object (object_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE contacts (
  contact_id      SERIAL
  contact_details TEXT,
  object_id       BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (object_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (object_id) REFERENCES object (object_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Then files are associated with those `objects`:

```
CREATE TABLE files (
  file_id         SERIAL,
  filename        TEXT
  object_id       BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (object_id) REFERENCES object (object_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Now, when you delete an `object`, the relevant `order` or `contact` together with all associated `files` will all be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Those tables will not allow having multiple files per order or contact.

You will need two additional mapping tables for order_id+files_id and contact_id+files_id,
and you should make files.file_id and primary key.

Comment: They will allow multiple files per order or contact because files.file_id is not unique.

Comment: but neither orders nor contacts has a place to store more than one file_id.

Comment: contacts.files_id will be 15456 for example. So you can have as many as records in "files" with id 15456. files.file_id is not unique :)

Comment: Not a good design, IMO. When you call something an id you're implying that it uniquely identifies something. I would suggest you go with @Mahmoud Gamal's answer.